# MySql Select Statement that should return a unique row

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns **name**, **rank**, **created_date** in **table1**.

I would like to

```
SELECT 
    name,
    rank for latest created_date,
    latest created_date, 
    difference between rank current created_date & previous date
FROM
    table1
```

There is only one record per person per created_date.

Output should be:

```
Sam 15 2011/10/05 -3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the difference, This is what I have done:    SELECT name,created_date,rank
    FROM table1 
    WHERE created_date = (SELECT created_date FROM table1 ORDER BY    created_date DESC LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  name,
  rank,
  created_date,
  rank - (
    SELECT rank FROM table1 AS bar
    WHERE bar.created_date < foo.created_date
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS diff 
FROM table1 AS foo
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: Re-reading your question, I think you want to get one output row *per person*, with the difference computed between the last two records for that person.  If so, a slightly more complicated solution is needed:

```
SELECT
  name,
  rank,
  created_date,
  rank - (
    SELECT rank FROM table1 AS bar
    WHERE bar.name = foo.name AND bar.created_date < foo.created_date
    ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS diff 
FROM table1 AS foo
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT name, MAX(created_date) AS created_date FROM table1
  GROUP BY name
) AS blah
```

Comment: I think I need to add the name also in the inner SELECT otherwise I am getting only the first record, its rank, date and difference. Should be SELECT
  name,
  rank,
  created_date,
  rank - (
    SELECT rank FROM table1 AS bar
    WHERE bar.created_date < foo.created_date AND bar.name = foo.name
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS diff 
FROM table1 AS foo
ORDER BY created_date DESC